# Vaadin java Class will not start

Tags: html, vaadin, designer, transfer

I took a class for login into a web application from this forum for testing.

I use the Vaadin designer for making a single page webapplication. A User should login and will transfer to the site which I've created with the designer. At the moment there is no Java connection for the Webapp and my only goal is to transfer from log in to the MainView page.

Today I tried it again and it doesn't work anymore.  I've done nothing on the Java side only expanded the designer file.

```
package com.example;


import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.AbstractLogin;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginForm;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{

    public MainView ( )
    {
        this.display();
    }

    private void display ( )
    {
        if ( Objects.isNull( VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute( User.class ) ) )
        {
            this.removeAll();
            this.add( this.makeLoginForm() );
        } else
        { // Else we have a User, so must be authenticated.
            this.removeAll();
            this.add( new MyContentView() );
        }
    }

    private LoginForm makeLoginForm ( )
    {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
        LoginForm component = new LoginForm();
        component.addLoginListener( ( AbstractLogin.LoginEvent loginEvent ) -> {
            Optional < User > user = authenticator.authenticate( loginEvent.getUsername() , loginEvent.getPassword() );
            if ( user.isPresent() )
            {
                VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute( User.class , user.get() );
                this.display();
            } else
            {
                component.setError( true );
            }
        } );
        return component;
    }
```

```
package com.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.accordion.Accordion;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.datepicker.DatePicker;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.Id;
import com.vaadin.flow.templatemodel.TemplateModel;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate;

/**
 * A Designer generated component for the my-content-view template.
 *
 * Designer will add and remove fields with @Id mappings but
 * does not overwrite or otherwise change this file.
 */
@Tag("my-content-view")
@JsModule("./my-content-view.js")
public class MyContentView extends PolymerTemplate<MyContentView.MyContentViewModel> {

    @Id("vaadinAccordion")
    private Accordion vaadinAccordion;
    @Id("label")
    private Label label;
    @Id("label1")
    private Label label1;
    @Id("birthday")
    private DatePicker birthday;
    @Id("vaadinButton")
    private Button vaadinButton;


    /**
     * Creates a new MyContentView.
     */
    public MyContentView() {
        // You can initialize any data required for the connected UI components here.
    }

    /**
     * This model binds properties between MyContentView and my-content-view
     */
    public interface MyContentViewModel extends TemplateModel {
        // Add setters and getters for template properties here.
    }
}
```

This is the error Massage after login and update the site

```
There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the exception message 'Error creating bean with name 'com.example.MainView': Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no element with id='vaadinAccordion' in the template file './my-content-view.js'. Cannot map it using @Id'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.MainView': Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no element with id='vaadinAccordion' in the template file './my-content-view.js'. Cannot map it using @Id
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:307)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117)
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:160)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:132)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:477)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:228)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:249)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:220)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:186)
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1516)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:472)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no element with id='vaadinAccordion' in the template file './my-content-view.js'. Cannot map it using @Id
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no element with id='vaadinAccordion' in the template file './my-content-view.js'. Cannot map it using @Id
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.IdCollector.collectedInjectedId(IdCollector.java:106)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.IdCollector.lambda$collectInjectedIds$1(IdCollector.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.IdCollector.collectInjectedIds(IdCollector.java:78)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.IdCollector.collectInjectedIds(IdCollector.java:67)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateDataAnalyzer.parseTemplate(TemplateDataAnalyzer.java:215)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateInitializer.<init>(TemplateInitializer.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate.<init>(PolymerTemplate.java:88)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate.<init>(PolymerTemplate.java:103)
    at com.example.MyContentView.<init>(MyContentView.java:38)
    at com.example.MainView.display(MainView.java:38)
    at com.example.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200)
    ... 74 more
```

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-button/src/vaadin-button.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-charts/src/vaadin-chart.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/src/vaadin-vertical-layout.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/src/vaadin-horizontal-layout.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/src/vaadin-date-picker.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-accordion/src/vaadin-accordion.js';

class MyContentView extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
<style include="shared-styles">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
<vaadin-horizontal-layout style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <vaadin-vertical-layout class="sidebar" style="flex-basis: calc(7*var(--lumo-size-s)); flex-shrink: 0; background-color: var(--lumo-contrast-5pct);">
  <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="flex-grow: 1; align-self: stretch;">
   <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="flex-grow: 1; align-self: stretch;">
    <vaadin-button>
      Button 
    </vaadin-button>
   </vaadin-vertical-layout>
   <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="flex-grow: 1; align-self: stretch;">
    <vaadin-button theme="primary">
      Primary 
    </vaadin-button>
   </vaadin-vertical-layout>
  </vaadin-vertical-layout>
  <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="flex-grow: 1; align-self: stretch;">
   <vaadin-button id="vaadinButton">
     Button 
   </vaadin-button>
   <vaadin-accordion></vaadin-accordion>
  </vaadin-vertical-layout>
 </vaadin-vertical-layout>
 <vaadin-vertical-layout class="content" style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: auto;">
  <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="align-self: stretch; height: 20%;">
   <vaadin-chart type="pie" title="Browser market shares in January, 2018" tooltip="">
    <vaadin-chart-series title="Brands" values="[[&quot;Chrome&quot;,61.41],[&quot;Internet Explorer&quot;,11.84],[&quot;Firefox&quot;,10.85],[&quot;Edge&quot;,4.67],[&quot;Safari&quot;,4.18],[&quot;Sogou Explorer&quot;,1.64],[&quot;Opera&quot;,1.6],[&quot;QQ&quot;,1.2],[&quot;Other&quot;,2.61]]"></vaadin-chart-series>
   </vaadin-chart>
  </vaadin-vertical-layout>
  <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="align-self: stretch; flex-grow: 1;">
   <vaadin-horizontal-layout theme="spacing" style="flex-grow: 1; height: 100%; align-self: stretch;">
    <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 30%;">
     <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="margin" style="height: 50%; align-self: stretch; width: 100%; padding: var(--lumo-space-m);">
      <label id="label1">Neuigkeiten - Letzter Monat</label>
     </vaadin-vertical-layout>
     <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="margin" style="height: 50%; align-self: stretch; flex-grow: 0; width: 100%; padding: var(--lumo-space-m);"></vaadin-vertical-layout>
    </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 100%;">
     <vaadin-vertical-layout style="width: 100%; height: 50%;">
      <label id="label">Meine Kurse</label>
     </vaadin-vertical-layout>
     <vaadin-vertical-layout style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"></vaadin-vertical-layout>
    </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 30%;">
     <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 100%; height: 50%; padding: var(--lumo-space-m);">
      <label>Mail</label>
     </vaadin-vertical-layout>
     <vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 100%; height: 50%; padding: var(--lumo-space-m);">
      <vaadin-date-picker label="Datum" placeholder="Pick a date" id="birthday">
        Datum 
      </vaadin-date-picker>
     </vaadin-vertical-layout>
    </vaadin-vertical-layout>
   </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
  </vaadin-vertical-layout>
 </vaadin-vertical-layout>
</vaadin-horizontal-layout>
`;
    }

    static get is() {
        return 'my-content-view';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(MyContentView.is, MyContentView);
```

Comment: Have you investigated into `There is no element with id='vaadinAccordion' in the template file`? Could you please add also the designer file?

Comment: Yes i´ve delete it and also put it into the designer again i will add the Designer file

Comment: There is also a error in the designer Mismatched property value (content | <width> | [initial | inherit | unset | revert])

Comment: here class="sidebar" style="flex-basis: calc(7*var(--lumo-size-s)

Comment: Ok i test by adding @PageTitel where the Logic goes and it never goes to MyContentView. Maybe because of the errors. I try another Designer js

Comment: The "HTML" in your diesign file has an accordion, but that has no ID set.  Since this is what the error states: could you please try to add it and see if this progresses the problem?

Comment: yes this was the Problem, i add the ID no it is working, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states:

```
There is no element with id='vaadinAccordion' in the template file
```

The "HTML" of the design file contains an accordion tag, but no
`id`-attribute:

```html
<vaadin-accordion></vaadin-accordion>
```